# How can I redirect/map localhost to something point to something else?

Tags: linux, docker, localhost

In my case, this problem is happening within a Docker container but at least partly it should be a generic linux questions.

I'm fighting with an application that I can't configure in the way it connects to another (local) application. It uses `http://localhost:8080` by out of the box and this can't be changed. I'm using docker in my setup and both containers are running in separate containers.

For reasons I can't run them in `network_mode=host` where one could reach the other through `localhost` so I'm looking for a way to "redirect" localhost within one container to the other. I also don't want to use IP addresses here as they may change.

Is there any way to have any kind of mapping that makes `localhost` be the alias of a different hostname? In my case `http://other-container:8080` is what I want and which would work perfectly. I can also totally live with not having a "real" localhost within that container.

So is there any way to do so?

Comment: "I also don't want to use IP addresses here" - but _can_ you use them? I thought access to "localhost:8080" is hardcoded. If IP addresses is a possibility, then you can use network aliases, no? http://other-container.local:8080, or something like that

Comment: Unfortunately no,  using IP addresses isn't an option as they are dynamic in the setup. They can and will change on boot time.

Comment: It also sounds to me like you should just use `http://other-container:8080` (it will work so long as both containers are on the same Docker-internal network).

Comment: @DavidMaze maybe I wasn't clear enough but I can't.